# python - unicode regex match - how do I search for the checkmark? ✓

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, unicode

I am trying to match against lines that contain a checkmark in them: ✓

I'm using python3.

The unicode encoding can be read about here: https://codepoints.net/U+2713?lang=en

The line I'm trying to match against looks like this:

```
✓ Chrome on MAC - MySite.com - version-1
```

`re.match("✓", line)` does not work.  `re.match("/u2713", line)` does not work either.

How can I determine if the `line` contains a ✓?

--- UPDATE ---

**solved**: apparently there was an invisible character of some sort preceding the ✓ and this caused the `match` operator to fail.  Thanks to @NickT and @EricDuminil for clueing me in.  Also, the `in` operator appears to be easier and safer, so I'm marking that answer as correct.

Comment: You could try one of these `ur"\u2713"` or `ur"\x{2713}"` or `ur"\u{2713}"` or `ur"✓"`

Comment: Also, make sure the target string is encoded in Unicode, i.e. `target = ur"✓ Chrome on MAC - MySite.com - version-1"`

Comment: If you're using Python 3, `u`'s in front of strings are meaningless.

Comment: Does the line *start with* the checkmark? `re.match` **only** matches from the start of the provided string, use `.search` to look anywhere in the string (or better yet, `in` if you don't need any wildcards).

Comment: @NickT Good comment. I hate `re.match` with a passion. It's simple enough to add a `'^'` to `re.search`, I don't understand why `re.match` is even here. It's a perfect method if you want to spend an hour looking for a stupid bug.

Comment: Thanks, @NickT, that was my problem

Comment: @EricDuminil I just spent over an hour looking for a stupid bug

Comment: @EricDuminil I think `re.match` doesn't go far enough; it should require that the provided pattern consumes the *entire* string. One of the few warts in Python that we're probably stuck with forever.

Comment: @NickT: What bothers me most about `re.match` is that the name really doesn't imply that the pattern should match from the beginning. For added confusion : In Java, it should match the whole string, in Python, it should match from the beginning and in Ruby, it could match anywhere. :-/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't even need any regex. You could use the [`in operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details):

```
>>> "✓" in "✓ Chrome on MAC - MySite.com - version-1"
True
>>> "✓" in "Chrome on MAC - MySite.com - version-1"
False
```

If you want to display the lines with a checkmark inside `'marks.txt'`, you can write:

```
with open('marks.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if "✓" in line:
            print(line, end='')
```

Answer (score 2):

For a fool-proof method, specify the character by name:

```
>>> line = '✓ Chrome on MAC - MySite.com - version-1'
>>> re.match('\N{CHECK MARK}', line)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 1), match='✓'>
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I determine if the line contains a ✓?

Example:

```
import re


text = '''
123 456 789
✓ 123 456 789
123 456 789
123 456 ✓ 789
123 456 789
'''

for m in re.finditer('^.*✓.*$', text, re.MULTILINE):
    print('line:', m.group(0))
```

Prints:

```
line: ✓ 123 456 789
line: 123 456 ✓ 789
```